# Eclipse: An internal error occurred during "Contacting Software Sites"

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Indigo. Every time I opened "Install New Software" I get a pop-up window with

> 'Contacting Software Sites' has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during "Contacting Software Sites".

and when I click the details, I get the following message

> An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

This error prevents me to install any software. Anybody knows the problem ?!

Answer (score 8):

This happened in my eclipse some time ago.

what i did is that i expanaded the error by clicking detail in error popup note down the url that caused it and deleted that in windows->preference->install/update->Available Software Sites

Comment: when you will expand contact site error . there should be a button or link on that error that will expand it

Comment: There is nothing other that a "details" button, and when I click on, I get "An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites".
java.lang.NullPointerException". But, there is no any link or any URL

Comment: have you lately upgraded your eclipse or install something that caused this error. if yes then try to revert it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the files in the cache from the following folder and install again from Help -> Install New Software -> [add update site URL] -> and so forth...

```
.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.p2\cache
```

And this location should be in your user's directory. For me it was like this:

```
C:\Users\rahmanmahbubur\.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.p2\cache
```